# Can I dispay more than one video in the HTML 5 video element?

Tags: html, video

I’m using the HTML5 `video` element to display video on my asp.net page.

How can I display multiple videos one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the change the `src attribute` of the video once the each video is ended.

Check out my fiddle where I have done this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tushar2289/z874X/)